# Linked list - Is this the correct way to refer to the next to next node of the current node

Tags: c

Currently 'L' is pointing to the current node. I want to make oldp equal to the node after current node using the pointer 'l'. So what im trying to say below is that oldp = the node after the current where 'l' is the pointer to the current node.

```
oldp = L->next->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 oldp=l->next;
```

is enough.....